# Destructuring assignment vs object property access in ES6

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ecmascript-6

what is the difference between `var bmw = cars.bmw` and `var {bmw} = cars` ? Which way is better?

```
var cars = {
    bmw: "M3",
    benz: "c250"
}

var bmw = cars.bmw // M3
var {bmw} = cars // M3
```

And I've seen people do this in Nodejs. Is it the same thing?

```
var {ObjectId} = require('mongodb')
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
```

Comment: Only you can decide which you like better, they do essentially the same. Usually when assigning only a single variable, there's not much conciseness advantage in using destructuring.

Comment: `var {bmw} = cars` __vs__ `var bmw = cars.bmw` you write `bmw` only once, hence less places to edit if you ever change that property. you have a nice alias syntax and a cleaner way (imo) for default values. Not sure about you, but that is enough for me :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On `bmw = cars.bmw` you are assigning an object property to a variable, whereas `var {bmw} = cars` destructuring an object into given variables list.

As the result there is no difference (*in your case*), the `bmw` will have desired `M3` value.

Moreover when destructuring the object you can *list several variables* to assign whilst `=` is *1-to-1* assignment where *right part is being assigned to the left*.

---

Also you can rename variable on destructuring like

```
const { bmw: BeeMWee } = cars;
```

Comment: "*but under the hood it behaves differently*" - how so? I'd argue contrariwise: while looking different syntactically, they have exactly the same semantics under the hood.

Comment: @Bergi that what I will read today's evening! Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @Bergi They are not exactly the same. Object destructuring assignment will break use of a properties getter. See: https://easy-peasy.now.sh/docs/api/computed.html#computed-properties-break-when-destructuring-a-computed-property-out-of-state

Comment: @Rob_vH That's rubbish. The semantics are *exactly* the same. The problem in the example code you linked is actually with running the getter inside vs outside of the `useStoreState` mapper function. Using the equivalent destructuring (`const isLoggedIn = useStoreState(({session: { isLoggedIn }}) => isLoggedIn);`) would work just fine, and using dot syntax outside of the callback (`const isLoggedIn = useStoreState(state => state.session).isLoggedIn`) would have exactly the same broken change detection.

Comment: @Bergi Fantastic clarification despite the unnecessary "rubbish" insult. The pattern shown there is extremely popular and in pull requests I often have to clarify to developers who think `const { thing } = accessor(some)` is a shorter version of `const thing = accessor(some.thing)`. This is a common use of destructuring assignment because it shortens the code. It however, neglects the fact that the latter returns the whole object prior to destructuring occurring. The semantics of the final step (dot assignment vs destr. assignment) are the _same_. The semantics of the overall operation are not

Comment: @Bergi your clarification regarding the mechanics is very helpful.

Comment: @Rob_vH Sorry for the strong language, I really dislike wrong information in official documentation

Comment: @Bergi it's all good. :) I think there's a _lot_ going on there other than the deconstruction. Immer is used under the hood and it's also very possible that a deep copy of the original state object is being returned and therefore the original getter isn't firing when deconstructed post function return.